# Generate unique ID from database PhpMyAdmin and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem with generating this unique ID.
Here's the table looks like:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUFSU.png)

Here's the rule for creating the ID:

1. The ID will looks like this: AAyyyymm00x

   - AA is the dest_code.
   - yyyy is the current year.
   - mm is the current month.
   - 00x is the registration number. And will be resetted each day to 1. And increased by 1 per-registration.
2. So the final looks will be: AA201604001

my code for controller:

```
public function tambah()
    {
        $this->data['namaNegara'] =  $this->registrasi_model->get_nama_negara();
        $this->data['main_view'] = 'program/administrasi/registrasi_form';
        $this->data['form_action'] = site_url('program/administrasi/registrasi/tambah');

        // Data untuk form.
        if (! $_POST) {
            $registrasi = (object) $this->registrasi_model->default_value;
        } else {
            $registrasi = $this->input->post(null, true);
        }   

        // Validasi.
        if (! $this->registrasi_model->validate('form_rules')) {
            $this->data['values'] = (object) $registrasi;
            $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
            return;
        }
        $destName = $registrasi['Nama_Negara'];
        echo $registrasi['No_Registrasi'] = $this->registrasi_model->generate_no_reg($destName);
    }
```

my code for model:

```
public function generate_no_reg($destName)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT Dest_Code from Destination WHERE Dest_Name= "$destName"');
        $id1 = $query->row()->Dest_Code;

        $query2 = 'SELECT Reg_ID FROM Registration ORDER BY Reg_ID DESC LIMIT 1';
        $lastid = $this->db->query($query2);
        $id2 = $lastid->row()->Reg_ID+1;

        $id3 = format_no_registrasi($id2);
        $kode = $id1.$id3;
        return $kode;

    }
```

my function code for format_no_registrasi:

```
function format_no_registrasi($no)
{ 
    $leadingzeros = '000';
    $no_reg = date('Y') . date('m') . substr($leadingzeros, 0, (-strlen($no))) . $no;
    return $no_reg;
}
```

Here's my error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4AgT.png)
 
The text that showing on the bottom is my ID i wanted but it dont have the Dest_Code.
Any help is very much appreciated. And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: With which part do you struggle? What have you tried? Maybe add the code that you already have to the question.

Comment: @Odi: sorry for not giving the detailed information. i just updated my question. the problem is i didnt get my dest_code and some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function generate_no_reg($destName)
{
    $this->db->select('Dest_Code');
    $this->db->from('Destination');
    $this->db->where('Dest_Name',$destName);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

I think this 'll work..Now try printing the result in controller.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need the "AA" from the database, and that's my problem

Comment: why can't you select it from database?

Comment: see my question, i added the code and the error im having

Comment: it still doesnt work. "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: try print_r(variable);  instead of echo variable;

Comment: It showing like this: stdClass Object ( [Dest_Code] => BD )

Comment: Yes, i was hoping to get BD into the _ _ 201604001 so it will be BD201604001. But it only showing 201604001

Comment: ok..Now try to pass that variable into function format_no_registrasi() and  append to $no_reg.

Comment: im using your code, but before returning the value i added this : $result = $query->row(); and return $result->Dest_Code;

Comment: you can use separate functions for both query. And load both model functions in controller.

Answer (score 0):

write function in codeigniter. In this function get last records from table and increase one value then add. before increase one need to split and put correct year and month then concat values of dest_code, yyyy ,mm and increased value. Then insert your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your model,

first get count of your records using : select count(*) from tbl. assign into some variable $maxcount

build your unique id...
$unique_id=$dest_code.date("Ym").str_pad($maxcount+1,3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

while inserting id into database use $unique_id.